# Defocusing TextBox by clicking it again

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus

I'm making a settings form, where user can assign custom hotkeys for the application. There's a TextBox, and by clicking it with mouse, it focuses and waits for one keypress and then defocuses (by focusing another label):

```
private void txtKey_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}

private void txtKey_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    label1.Focus();
}
```

Is there a way to defocus focused TextBox (and cancel the key assinging process), by either clicking it again with mouse, or by clicking the GroupBox around it? I can't figure out how to check if TextBox was already focused when clicked (because when clicked, it gets focused before I can test if it's focused). Of course I can add a button "Cancel" next to the TextBox, but that's not what I want.

There is no Click-event for GroupBox, so I can't defocus TextBox by clicking GroupBox around it. Or can I somehow?

Comment: Why NOT just use the `Panel` control inside `GroupBox`, `Panel` has the `MouseClick` event.

Comment: This kind of works. I'll use this if I can't figure out better solution. Problem with this is that I have to set Click event to all labels inside that panel too and add Panels to all GroupBoxes. And GroupBox borders still won't work, so little dirty approach, but thanks anyway!

Comment: If the dialog has no other control to focus, other than the OK and Cancel button, then what is the point of "cancelling" at all?  The user simply has no good other reason to use the keyboard.

Comment: User can always want to hit esc or enter (like I do often), to close or apply and close dialog. And doing this will register that key to the hotkey. Of course user can always click cancel to close dialog without saving, but it feels more "professional" to be able to cancel assigning process by clicking textfield again. And on my own answer, I have working solution. (added pic to show portion of the dialog box, active textbox is different colored and waiting for keystroke. http://www.saunalahti.fi/arka80/web/hotkey.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to private_meta for getting me to right direction (in comments)! I set the flag with click event, and before setting the flag, testing if flag is set. So first click does not find the flag, but second will. And flag is cleared within textbox Enter-event (which fires before Click-event). Now every other click focuses and every other defocuses textbox, as I wanted.

```
private void txtKey_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Tag = null;
}

private void txtKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (textBox.Tag != null) label1.Focus();
    textBox.Tag = "clicked";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set/remove the Focus with

```
Keyboard.Focus = null;
```

You can also register to the following event:

```
public event MouseButtonEventHandler PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown
```

This event fires every time you click on the TextBox, thus you can set the Focus there if you want to.

For Winforms there is a way as well. I'm not proficient in it, but here would be a way:
Make a textBox (e.g. named textBoxFocus) that lies outside your window. Size it 1, 1 and move it to -10,-10 for example. Then you can register to the Click event and write

```
textBoxFocus.Focus();
```

It's a bit of a roundabout way, but should achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but these are WPF related stuff, not winforms?

Comment: Hi, no problem! But isn't that the same thing than to focus a label (with no text), as described in my question? Problem is that if I register TextBox click event to focus another control, I am never able to focus TextBox to assign hotkey. What I want is to focus some other control _if I click TextBox again_ when it is already focused.

Comment: Then what you can do is either use what @sallushan said in his reply to you, use a panel. Otherwise, you need to register to the GotFocus and LostFocus event, and when you GET the focus, set a flag, when you Click and you have the flag set, you know you need to unfocus. Then, reset the flag.

Comment: I tried this, using Enter event (it was under the focus gategory in VS). It's just that when I click the TextBox, Enter event fires before Click event, so the flag is always set before I can check it with Click event.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way is that, you may use a bool flag here.
Algorithm:

```
By default, the bool value is 0;
If(Textbox Selected && flag = 0)
    Do your task; and flag = 1;
```

I hope I could satisfy your query and you can follow this algorithm.